# Elasticsearch, not able to get proper result using date range query

Tags: date, elasticsearch, filter, range, mapping

Elasticsearch index mapping format,

```
"mappings": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "_source": {"enabled": "true"},
        "properties": {
            "topic": {"type": "text"},
            "value": {"type": "text"},
            "date": {"type": "date", "format": "YYYY-MM-DD"}
            }
        }
```

search query is,

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/sample_index/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"range": {"date": {"gte": "2023-01-14", "lte": "2023-01-16"}}}]}}}'
```

I should have got the result based on filter, but i am getting all the documents saved for index **sample_index** , not getting result based on date filter

tried with **must** as well,

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/sample_index/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"date": {"gte": "2023-01-14", "lte": "2023-01-16"}}}]}}}'
```

no luck :(
Will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace date format "YYYY-MM-DD" to "yyyy-MM-dd"